# Pandas: reorganizing a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe with four columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': {1:'Aaron', 2:'Bobby', 3:'Carl'},  
               'job': {1:'mechanic', 2:'carpenter', 3:'plumber'},
               'experience': {1:12, 2:23, 3:14},
               'type': {1:'owner',2:'contractor',3:'assistant'}},
              columns=['name','job','experience','type'])
df
```

I'd like to use pandas to reshape the data so that `names` is the index and `job` is a column header, with `experience` and `type` as subheaders for the columns -- i.e., under the `mechanic` column, there would be a sub-column for `experience` and `type`, and the same under the `carpenter` column, etc.

I've tried using

```
df.set_index(['name', 'job']).unstack('job')
```

But then `experience` and `type` are the top level rather than `job`. Is there a way I can change this to make `job` the top level of column header?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Almost what you want `df.pivot(index='name',columns='job')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`MultiIndex.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.swaplevel.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.swaplevel(0,1)
print (df)
job    carpenter   mechanic    plumber   carpenter mechanic    plumber
      experience experience experience        type     type       type
name                                                                  
Aaron        NaN       12.0        NaN        None    owner       None
Bobby       23.0        NaN        NaN  contractor     None       None
Carl         NaN        NaN       14.0        None     None  assistant
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is definitely an improvement, but is there a way for `experience` and `type` to be grouped side-by-side under the `job` heading?

Comment: No, it is impossible, unfortunately. You can group all levels, but last never.

Comment: You can check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object) - it is called sparse Multiindex and it can be turn off by `pd.set_option('display.multi_sparse', False)`.

Comment: Also, when I try this I keep getting `KeyError: 'name'` -- I can't figure out why :(

Comment: Maybe some space in column name, check `print df.columns`.